# How to fix illegal string offset warnings - I'm using an array or object as a key and can't see where

Tags: php, wordpress, simplexml

Firstly, sorry for ANOTHER post about this same thing, but reading everyone else's has not yielded the results I'm looking for unfortunately.

I'm having issues with Illegal string offset and Uninitialized string offset warnings/notices.

I'm getting the following php warnings:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'height'
Warning: Illegal string offset 'width'
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 (for both height and width)
```

Here's the "Location" and "Caller":

```
Location: wp-includes/media.php:993

Caller:
1. get_sidebar()
wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/single.php:43

2. locate_template()
wp-includes/general-template.php:111

3. load_template('wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/sidebar.php')
wp-includes/template.php:653

4. dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1')
wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/sidebar.php:19

5. WP_Widget->display_callback()
wp-includes/widgets.php:769

6. WP_Widget_Media->widget()
wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php:377

7. WP_Widget_Media_Image->render_media()
wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-media.php:248

8. _wp_get_image_size_from_meta()
wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-media-image.php:213
```

I've been tweaking my code for hours trying to figure out where I've gone wrong. It seems clear that I'm trying to use the simplexml object as a key... but I can't seem to figure out where my issue is exactly. I think too many hours looking at the same code!

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
function bodhi_svgs_response_for_svg( $response, $attachment, $meta ) {

    if ( $response['mime'] == 'image/svg+xml' && empty( $response['sizes'] ) ) {

        $svg_path = get_attached_file( $attachment->ID );

        if ( ! file_exists( $svg_path ) ) {
            // If SVG is external, use the URL instead of the path
            $svg_path = $response[ 'url' ];
        }

        $dimensions = bodhi_svgs_get_dimensions( $svg_path );

        $response[ 'sizes' ] = array(
            'full' => array(
                'url' => $response[ 'url' ],
                'width' => $dimensions->width,
                'height' => $dimensions->height,
                'orientation' => $dimensions->width > $dimensions->height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait'
                )
            );

    }

    return $response;

}
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'bodhi_svgs_response_for_svg', 10, 3 );

function bodhi_svgs_get_dimensions( $svg ) {

    $svg = simplexml_load_file( $svg );

    if ( $svg === FALSE ) {

        $width = '0';
        $height = '0';

    } else {

        $attributes = $svg->attributes();
        $width = (string) $attributes->width;
        $height = (string) $attributes->height;

    }

    return (object) array( 'width' => $width, 'height' => $height );

}
```

Here's the core code that is affecting my situation for reference:

```
function _wp_get_image_size_from_meta( $size_name, $image_meta ) {
    if ( $size_name === 'full' ) {
        return array(
            absint( $image_meta['width'] ),
            absint( $image_meta['height'] ),
        );
    } elseif ( ! empty( $image_meta['sizes'][ $size_name ] ) ) {
        return array(
            absint( $image_meta['sizes'][ $size_name ]['width'] ),
            absint( $image_meta['sizes'][ $size_name ]['height'] ),
        );
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the illegal string offset? Because I'm not seeing anything that would obviously cause that.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the function from core that is causing me issues. It's the first `return array(...);`

Comment: You should try `print_r($size_name)` and `print_r($image_meta)` in that core code and see if they are what you expected.

Comment: You haven't shown your call to `_wp_get_image_size_from_meta`, but it seems quite likely that you're passing a string as the second argument. Maybe a file name, instead of the details of that file?

Comment: @cjmling I have done that, `print_r($size_name)` shows `string(4) "full"` and `print_r($image_meta)` shows `string(0) ""`. I'm so confused at this point.
@GregSchmidt It's core code that calls it:
WP_Widget->display_callback()
wp-includes/widgets.php:769
WP_Widget_Media->widget()
wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php:377
WP_Widget_Media_Image->render_media()
wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-media.php:248
_wp_get_image_size_from_meta()
wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-media-image.php:213

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue... and as I had imagined, it was literally a minute fix, I was just overlooking it.

I was able to avoid the warnings and notices when I changed my code's `$response['sizes']` name from `'full'` to `'custom'` and then adding CSS for the image widget img tag if the src is SVG.

```
$response[ 'sizes' ] = array(
    'custom' => array( // changed from 'full' to 'custom'
        'url' => $response[ 'url' ],
        'width' => $dimensions->width,
        'height' => $dimensions->height,
        'orientation' => $dimensions->width > $dimensions->height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait'
    )
);
```

And the CSS to make sure the image widget using SVG doesn't display at 1x1px:

```
.widget_media_image img[src$=".svg"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who chimed in to help.